# replace string php with html mailto tag

Tags: php, html

I have an string email address that comes from user input($option['footer_email']) and I want to replace it with mailto html tag. So far I tried couple of approaches and tried to use str_replace() as followed, but it didn't work out.

```
$email = array($option['footer_email']);
$replace = array('<a href="mailto:$option['footer_email']">$option['footer_email']</a>');
echo str_replace($email, $replace, $option['footer_email']);
```

and it returns syntax error, unexpected 'footer_email' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

I also tried to use preg_replace() but that one didn't help. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: wow easy. dont make syntax errors. see that $option[**'** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: In PHP `'` is not the same as `"` - variables won't be interpreted inside `'` marks : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php .. try `"<a href=\"mailto:{$option['footer_email']}\">{$option['footer_email']}</a>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$email = array($option['footer_email']);
$replace = array('<a href="mailto:"' . $option['footer_email'] . '">' .$option['footer_email'] . '</a>');
echo str_replace($email, $replace, $option['footer_email']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$email = $option['footer_email'];
$replace = '<a href="mailto:'.$option['footer_email'].'">'.$option['footer_email'].'</a>';
echo str_replace($email, $replace, $option['footer_email']);
```

Basically your variable is not read as it is part of the string.

Why do you have to do the `str_replace`? Why not just do this?

```
echo '<a href="mailto:'.$option['footer_email'].'">'.$option['footer_email'].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

please check your Apostrophe opening and closing properly, here this is working example with a dummy value

```
$option['footer_email'] = 'test@test.com';
$email = array($option['footer_email']);
$replace = array("<a href='mailto:$option[footer_email]'>$option[footer_email]</a>");
echo str_replace($email, $replace, $option['footer_email']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$option['footer_email']="waseem@waseem.com";
    $email = array($option['footer_email']);
    $replace = '<a href="mailto:'.$option['footer_email'].'">'.$option['footer_email'].'</a>';
    $replace_val= str_replace($email, $replace, $option['footer_email']);
    //check By var_dump
    var_dump($replace_val);
    //check By Print_r
    print_r($replace_val);
    //check By echo
    echo $replace_val;
```